# Is there an open source library that offers geodesic buffering of large polygons?

Tags: buffer, geodesic

I need to buffer some large polygons and minimize distortion. Is there an open source library that offers negative and positive geodesic buffering of large polygons? I am aware ESRI has an implementation but it is closed source.

Comment: Give an example of such large polygon. Define minimized distortion.

Comment: let's say the Pacific Ocean or some big country like Canada. Distortion ideally would be < 1 meter great circle distance from any given input vertex.

Comment: I would try PostGIS and ST_Buffer with geography datatype http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html.

Comment: Looking at the docs: “ For geography this may not behave as expected if object is sufficiently large that it falls between two UTM zones or crosses the dateline”